# Is there a way to bind Word content controls to a custom XML Part using office-js?

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, office-js

I'm pretty new to the Office.js/Word.js features.

Trying to determine if there is there a way to bind Word content controls to a custom XML Part using the current feature sets for Office (JavaScript) Add-Ins. If not, anyone know if this feature has been requested? It can be done in the VBA and VSTO object models using by assigning an XML Mapping using XPATH.

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: hi, I am stuck on the same problem. Did you found any way to data bind using javascript api?

Answer (score 0):

there is no API to directly do this, however you can achieve it using OOXML insertion. Make sure to get the OOXML that has an XML mapping and the insert the OOXML using range.insertOOXML(ooxml, "replace") option. (contentcontrol.insertOoxml(ooxml, "replace") will also work.

Comment: Thanks, Juan, for the very helpful input! Do you have a good source for minimal ooxml snippets for bound content controls (repeating and otherwise)? When I use the API to read the ooxml for an existing content control, it is huge.

Comment: OOXML is extremely verbose, but this article explains how to generate a minimal OOXML. https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/docs/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml.md

Comment: @JuanBalmori I am stuck in the same problem. The above link doesn't work for me. Can you send me an updated link?

Comment: @JuanBalmori how can I do this - `Make sure to get the OOXML that has an XML mapping`?

Comment: The article has been moved to [Create better add-ins ...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml?view=word-js-preview)