# JavaScript equivalent of a `XMLMapping.SetMapping`

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins

Is there any method in JavaScript API equivalent to [this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.xmlmapping.setmapping)? I want to be able to map Custom XML parts to content controls in MS Word through an add-in I am building. The docs I find are only of `C#` or `VBA` but my codebase is in React (JavaScript).

So I found [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121540/is-there-a-way-to-bind-word-content-controls-to-a-custom-xml-part-using-office-j) related to my question. But can I know how I can use `insertOoxml`? And what are some example OOXML to do so?

**UPDATE**

I know how to add a custom XML through an API. All I want to do is to figure out how I can map some content controls to it so that whatever change I do to one content control, reflects in the other too.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get control of Word's built-in XML mapping with Office JavaScript the way you can with VBA. You would have to develop a system of your own.

You should use the ContentControl APIs in the host-specific Word APIs, especially the  onDataChanged event (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.contentcontrol?view=word-js-preview#ondatachanged) to detect when the data in a content control has changed.

You can use the `ContentControl.id` or `ContentControl.tag` properties to identify the controls that should share the same data.
The custom XML part that has the data should also have an element or attribute that stores an array of the ids (or the tags) of the content controls that should use that data.

But don't use the CustomXMLPart API in the Common APIs that you linked to. It is complicated to mix the Common APIs with the Word host-specific APIs. Since you have to use the host-specific Word APIs for the ContentControls, you should also use the CustomXMLParts APIs in the host-specific Word APIs. For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.customxmlpart?view=word-js-preview

When the `ContentControl.onDataChanged` event is triggered, your handler code should change the data in the custom XML part to match the new data. It should also use the stored content control ids (or tags) in the XML part to identify the other content controls that should get the new data. Use the `ContentControl.insertText` method to change the text.

Make sure you use the [preview API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/word-preview-apis) (as of today, it is in preview).